# Gives java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.ArrayAdapter.clear()' on a null object reference

Tags: android

```
    package com.example.admin.sunshine.app;

    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.os.AsyncTask;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
    import android.util.Log;
    import android.view.LayoutInflater;
    import android.view.Menu;
    import android.view.MenuInflater;
    import android.view.MenuItem;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.ViewGroup;
    import android.widget.AdapterView;
    import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
    import android.widget.ListView;
    import android.net.Uri;
    import org.json.JSONArray;
    import org.json.JSONException;
    import org.json.JSONObject;
    import java.io.BufferedReader;
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.io.InputStream;
    import java.io.InputStreamReader;
    import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
    import java.net.URL;
    import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.Arrays;
    import java.util.Date;
    import java.util.List;
     /**
     * Created by admin on 12/02/2016.
     */
    public class ForecastFragment extends Fragment {
    private ArrayAdapter<String> mForecastAdapter;

    public ForecastFragment() {
    }
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle saveInstanceState)
    {
      super.onCreate(saveInstanceState);
        setHasOptionsMenu(true);
    }
    @Override
    public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu,MenuInflater inflater)
    {
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.forecastfragment,menu);
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)
    {
        int id=item.getItemId();
        if(id==R.id.action_refresh)
        {
            FetchWeatherTask weatherTask=new FetchWeatherTask();
            weatherTask.execute("London ");
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container,      false);

        String[] forecastArray={
                "Today - Sunny - 88/63",
                "Tomorrow - Cloudy - 72/63",
                "Wens - Sunny - 88/63",

        };
        List<String> weekForecast = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(forecastArray));

        ArrayAdapter<String> mForecastAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), R.layout.list_item_forecast, R.id.list_item_forecast_textview, weekForecast);


        ListView listView = (ListView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.listview_forecast);
        listView.setAdapter(mForecastAdapter);
        //listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
          //  @Override
          //  public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long l) {
         //       String forecast=mForecastAdapter.getItem(position);
         //       Intent intent=new Intent(getActivity(),DetailActivity.class).putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,forecast);
         //       startActivity(intent);
         //   }
       // });


        return rootView;
    }
    private class FetchWeatherTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String[]> {

        private final String LOG_TAG = FetchWeatherTask.class.getSimpleName();
        private String getReadableDateString(long time){
            // Because the API returns a unix timestamp (measured in seconds),
            // it must be converted to milliseconds in order to be converted to valid date.
            Date date = new Date(time * 1000);
            SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("E, MMM d");
            return format.format(date).toString();
        }

        /**
         * Prepare the weather high/lows for presentation.
         */
        private String formatHighLows(double high, double low) {
            // For presentation, assume the user doesn't care about tenths of a degree.
            long roundedHigh = Math.round(high);
            long roundedLow = Math.round(low);

            String highLowStr = roundedHigh + "/" + roundedLow;
            return highLowStr;
        }

        /**
         * Take the String representing the complete forecast in JSON Format and
         * pull out the data we need to construct the Strings needed for the wireframes.
         *
         * Fortunately parsing is easy:  constructor takes the JSON string and converts it
         * into an Object hierarchy for us.
         */
        private String[] getWeatherDataFromJson(String forecastJsonStr, int numDays)
                throws JSONException {

            // These are the names of the JSON objects that need to be extracted.
            final String OWM_LIST = "list";
            final String OWM_WEATHER = "weather";
            final String OWM_TEMPERATURE = "temp";
            final String OWM_MAX = "max";
            final String OWM_MIN = "min";
            final String OWM_DATETIME = "dt";
            final String OWM_DESCRIPTION = "main";

            JSONObject forecastJson = new JSONObject(forecastJsonStr);
            JSONArray weatherArray = forecastJson.getJSONArray(OWM_LIST);

            String[] resultStrs = new String[numDays];
            for(int i = 0; i < weatherArray.length(); i++) {
                // For now, using the format "Day, description, hi/low"
                String day;
                String description;
                String highAndLow;

                // Get the JSON object representing the day
                JSONObject dayForecast = weatherArray.getJSONObject(i);

                // The date/time is returned as a long.  We need to convert that
                // into something human-readable, since most people won't read "1400356800" as
                // "this saturday".
                long dateTime = dayForecast.getLong(OWM_DATETIME);
                day = getReadableDateString(dateTime);

                // description is in a child array called "weather", which is 1 element long.
                JSONObject weatherObject = dayForecast.getJSONArray(OWM_WEATHER).getJSONObject(0);
                description = weatherObject.getString(OWM_DESCRIPTION);

                // Temperatures are in a child object called "temp".  Try not to name variables
                // "temp" when working with temperature.  It confuses everybody.
                JSONObject temperatureObject = dayForecast.getJSONObject(OWM_TEMPERATURE);
                double high = temperatureObject.getDouble(OWM_MAX);
                double low = temperatureObject.getDouble(OWM_MIN);

                highAndLow = formatHighLows(high, low);
                resultStrs[i] = day + " - " + description + " - " + highAndLow;
            }
            for(String s: resultStrs){
                Log.v(LOG_TAG, "Forecast entry: " + s);
            }

            return resultStrs;
        }
        @Override
        protected String[] doInBackground(String... params) {
            if(params.length==0){
                return null;
            }
            // These two need to be declared outside the try/catch
            // so that they can be closed in the finally block.
            HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
            BufferedReader reader = null;

            // Will contain the raw JSON response as a string.
            String forecastJsonStr = null;
            String format="json";
            String units="metric";
            int numDays=7;
            String parID="44db6a862fba0b067b1930da0d769e98";

            try {
                // Construct the URL for the OpenWeatherMap query
                // Possible parameters are avaiable at OWM's forecast API page, at
                // http://openweathermap.org/API#forecast
                final String FORECAST_BASE_URL="http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast/daily?";
                final String QUERY_PARAM="q";
                final String FORMAT_PARAM="mode";
                final String UNITS_PARAM="units";
                final String DAYS_PARAM="cnt";
                final String ID_PARAM="appid";
                Uri builtUri = Uri.parse(FORECAST_BASE_URL).buildUpon()
                        .appendQueryParameter(QUERY_PARAM, params[0])
                        .appendQueryParameter(FORMAT_PARAM, format)
                        .appendQueryParameter(UNITS_PARAM, units)
                        .appendQueryParameter(DAYS_PARAM, Integer.toString(numDays))
                        .appendQueryParameter(ID_PARAM, parID)
                        .build();


                URL url = new URL(builtUri.toString());
                Log.v(LOG_TAG, "Built URI " + builtUri.toString());

                // Create the request to OpenWeatherMap, and open the connection
                urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
                urlConnection.connect();

                // Read the input stream into a String
                InputStream inputStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();
                StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
                if (inputStream == null) {
                    // Nothing to do.
                    return null;
                }
                reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));

                String line;
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    // Since it's JSON, adding a newline isn't necessary (it won't affect parsing)
                    // But it does make debugging a *lot* easier if you print out the completed
                    // buffer for debugging.
                    buffer.append(line + "\n");
                }

                if (buffer.length() == 0) {
                    // Stream was empty.  No point in parsing.
                    return null;
                }
                forecastJsonStr = buffer.toString();
                Log.v(LOG_TAG, "Forecast JSON String: " +forecastJsonStr);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Error ", e);
                // If the code didn't successfully get the weather data, there's no point in attemping
                // to parse it.
                return null;
            } finally {
                if (urlConnection != null) {
                    urlConnection.disconnect();
                }
                if (reader != null) {
                    try {
                        reader.close();
                    } catch (final IOException e) {
                        Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Error closing stream", e);
                    }
                }
            }
            try {
                return getWeatherDataFromJson(forecastJsonStr, numDays);
            }catch(JSONException e){
                Log.e(LOG_TAG, e.getMessage(), e);
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
           return null;        }
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String[] result){
         if(result !=null)
          {
             mForecastAdapter.clear();
         }
                for(String dayForecastStr:result){
                    mForecastAdapter.add(dayForecastStr);
                }
            }
        }


}
```

**LOGCAT**

```
02-16 10:44:03.159    2539-2539/com.example.admin.sunshine.app E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.admin.sunshine.app, PID: 2539
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.ArrayAdapter.clear()' on a null object reference
            at com.example.admin.sunshine.app.ForecastFragment$FetchWeatherTask.onPostExecute(ForecastFragment.java:272)
            at com.example.admin.sunshine.app.ForecastFragment$FetchWeatherTask.onPostExecute(ForecastFragment.java:97)
            at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:632)
            at android.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java:177)
            at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:645)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
```

Comment: There is no question here.

Comment: Change `ArrayAdapter<String> mForecastAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), R.layout.list_item_forecast, R.id.list_item_forecast_textview, weekForecast);
` to `mForecastAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), R.layout.list_item_forecast, R.id.list_item_forecast_textview, weekForecast);
`

Answer (score 0):

In your `onCreateView()` method, you create a local variable `mForecastAdapter` instead of using `mForecastAdapter` of Fragment. so `mForecastAdapter` of Fragment still be null in `onPostExecute()` method.

Answer (score 0):

check and handle null pointer before calling method

```
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String[] result){
  if(result !=null)
  {
     if(mForecastAdapter!=null){
         mForecastAdapter.clear();
     }
  } 
  for(String dayForecastStr:result){
       if(mForecastAdapter!=null){
           mForecastAdapter.add(dayForecastStr);
       }
  }
}
```